# How to compare the given date is 2 days older in java

Tags: java

How to compare that the given date is 2 days older than the current date?

Will `.243Z` make any difference based on the timezone?

Given date: `"2023-05-20T08:32:23.243Z"`

Need to compare given date with current date if it is 2 days before/ago.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 days older"? Like "exactly 2 days ago" or more like "the day before yesterday" which could be about 3 days depending on the time? And what did you try so far?

Comment: Given date of what data type?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS it is in String

Comment: 2 days older than what ? Today? In the same timezone ? Is the time relevant? Your question needs more details

Comment: Check out the java.time.LocalDate package. It provides everything you need: [JavaDoc LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: The _.243_ there is the milliseconds, the _Z_ character has no correlation to it.  The _Z_ is a way to represent the time-zone at the _UTC_, which is also referred to as the _Zulu_ time-zone.  Thus, that time-stamp was calculated with a _0_ offset, in terms of time-zone.

Comment: 2023-06-12T10:49:010Z In this case seconds having three digits how to solve this

Answer (score 3):

Parse your date to `OffsetDateTime` instance say givenDate, and than create `OffsetDateTime currDate = new OffsetDateTime();`After that do

```
boolean res = currDate.minusDays(2).isAfter(givenDate);
```

If your res is true than your given days is earlier (older) than two days before

Comment: How to solve this 2023-06-12T10:49:010Z

Comment: The line to parse it would be:
        OffsetDateTime testDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(testDateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);

But your String is problematic - Look at your time part "...10:49:010Z" - the number of seconds is '010' - you got an extra digit there is meant to be '01' or '10'? Remove extra-digit and you should be fine

Comment: right , which one to remove need to figure out

Answer (score 2):

#### steps to perform

- parse the `String` to an `OffsetDateTime`
- get the current `OffsetDateTime` with the same offset
- calculate the difference in days using the date only while disregarding the time of day
- check if the result is 2 or older

#### code example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String givenDate = "2023-05-20T08:32:23.243Z";
    // parse the String
    OffsetDateTime givenOffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(givenDate);
    // get the current date and time in the same zone (UTC)
    OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // calculate the time difference of the dates (disregarding time of day)
    Period period = Period.between(
                        givenOffsetDateTime.toLocalDate(),
                        now.toLocalDate()
                    );
    // print the result including a check for 2 days or older
    System.out.println(
            String.format("%s is %d days older than %s\nwhich means it is %s days in the past",
                            givenOffsetDateTime.toLocalDate(),
                            period.getDays(),
                            now.toLocalDate(),
                            period.getDays() < 2 ? "less than 2" : "2 or more"
                        )
            );
}
```

#### example output

```
2023-05-20 is 18 days older than 2023-06-07
which means it is 2 or more days in the past
```

Comment: Have clubbed both the answers
String givenDate = "2023-05-20T08:32:23.243Z";
OffsetDateTime givenOffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(givenDate);
        // get the current date and time in the same zone (UTC)
        OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        boolean res = now.minusDays(2).isAfter(givenOffsetDateTime);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a resource.

The time-stamp has a *milliseconds* field, the *"Z"* is a different field.

*Z* is used to represent the time-zone at the *[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)*, which is also referred to as the *Zulu* time-zone.
Which, stems from military and aeronautical applications, which use a *[phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)*, where *Z* is *Zulu*.

> *"Since the NATO phonetic alphabet word for Z is "Zulu", UTC is sometimes known as "Zulu time". This is especially true in aviation, where "Zulu" is the universal standard."*

This format is widely used throughout computer science.

The format is defined in *[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)*.

A *[time-zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)* simply defines an offset, from the *UTC*—negative numbers are *West*, towards America, and positive numbers are *East*, towards *Asia*.

For example, if you're time-stamp had the following format

```
2023-05-20T08:32:23.243-0400
```

The *"-0400"* signifies an offset in hours and minutes.
Thus, *negative 4 hours and 0 minutes*.

Which, depending on whether *[Day Light Saving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)* is currently being observed, will be either the *[Atlantic Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_Time_Zone)*, or the *[Eastern Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone)*.